# NAT plug-in for Windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

I want to forward some broadcasts through a NAT gateway on a Windows CE device. This should be possible with a NAT plug-in.

- Which kind of NAT plug-ins coul do this job?
- What tools do need I for development?

Comment: Are you looking for something [programmatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887916.aspx) or an already-built tool?

Comment: I think CreateIpForwardEntry will not suffice to forward broadcasts. Further some packets should be modified, so that I need a programmatic solution (NAT plug-in).

Comment: @Chris: Where have all the news-group members (platbuilder) gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requried NAT plug-ing is a [NAT editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883109.aspx).
The Visual Studio 2005/2008 is sufficient for developing a DLL for Windows CE.